How to connect a Nintendo Switch Joy-Con to PC via Bluetooth?
I asked a while ago on how to connect a Wiimote to a PC via bluetooth. I got no replies, so I'm guessing no one knows how to do this, so I was wondering if Joy-Cons are a good substitute for Wii remotes. I want to use the motion sensors from a remote to make some cool games like Wii Sports.
I was also told that PCs and Wii remotes can connect from many websites, but I have not been able to get them to connect. Is this an issue with Joy-Cons too?
If it's possible to use a Joy-Con in a PC game, how do I make it work?

Is it possible? Almost certainly. As you noted in your other question, there are emulators that support the hardware - what did you discover when you looked into how they solved the problem?

I never really thought of it that way, btw, so thanks. I appreciate it.

You're welcome & good luck! Something that might also possibly help is this SO post about reading wiimote data.

Yes, it is possible to connect Joy-Cons to a Windows PC. I experimented with this for my students a couple of years ago, and just confirmed the same method still works today on Windows 10:

In Windows, open your start menu and type "Bluetooth" then select "Bluetooth and other device settings" when it pops up as a suggestion.

Click "+ Add Bluetooth or other device" at the top of the settings window.

Select "Bluetooth: Mice, keyboards, pens, or audio and other kinds of Bluetooth devices"

Hold the Sync button on your Joy-Con until its LEDs start flashing in a sweeping pattern.

"Joy-Con (L)" or "Joy-Con (R)" should show up in the list of devices you can pair with. Select that.
If you're prompted for a PIN (I wasn't), use 0000 or 1234.

You'll get a message saying "Your device is ready to go!".
The LEDs may still be flashing/sweeping, but don't worry, that doesn't mean it failed. The Joy-Con is just waiting for software to tell it to do something different with its lights, and we haven't run a game that does that yet.


To confirm you're getting controller input, open your start menu and type "controller", then select "Set up USB game controllers" when it pops up as a suggestion.
You'll see "Wireless Gamepad - status: OK" in the menu - that's the Joy-Con. Select it and click "Properties". A window will pop with a Test tab that visualizes the input from the gamepad. Press buttons/move the stick and you'll see the visualization update. Don't worry that the "Axes" section doesn't update - the motion data is still coming though, it's just that this old Windows dialog doesn't know how to read it.
To start using this in a game in, e.g. Unity, you can use a free library like JoyconLib (MIT licensed). I've verified this pulls in the motion sensor data and generates a usable orientation in Unity, though for my students I had to make a few modifications to make it better match the Unity coordinate system. I can provide those details if that's relevant for your project.
To turn off the Joy-Con, press the Sync button once. It will disappear from the "Game Controllers" window. Hold the Sync button again to get the lights cycling, then press a face button and it should re-pair without going through the Bluetooth settings again.

Cool! Will Joy-Cons work on a web page and stop the flashing/sweeping there?

That's a different question than the one you asked. To save yourself and others' time, be sure to specify your full application in your question post from the start — e.g. tagging your question [tag:JavaScript] and asking "How can I access a Joy-Con's motion sensor data from a web page?"

Doing a quick search for "joy-con javascript" yields results like this one: How to detect joy-con input/motion controls in HTML5 JavaScript — does that answer your question?

Oh, yeah! That helps. Btw, I was just hoping to get a little bit more information from LudoProf since he had some experience on the subject.

LudoProf is my alt account I use when I'm not on my personal devices. I'd have tested the web case when I wrote this answer if I knew web was your target platform, but unfortunately I'm away from home and can't access my Joy-Cons to test just now.

Got back home to access my Joy-Cons. I've confirmed I can connect to them via the JavaScript Gamepad API, but this seems to only access the buttons and analog sticks. I don't see an obvious way to access motion sensor readings within a web page - the Joy-Con's .pose property is undefined. That will take some more research, and it might not be possible to access it at all with the currently available APIs.
